# GeoServer: Can Min/Max Scales be set on Groups of Rules or Layers?

Tags: geoserver, symbology, ogc

I would like to symbolize a line layer with different rules at different scales and could use some help figuring out the most efficient way to do so.

I have a layer of roads and I would like to symbolize the layer based on 5 scale ranges (1 Mill - 500K, 500K - 250K, 250K - 100K, 100K - 50K, and <50K). Within these ranges I have rules based on an attribute that classifies the type of road. As I zoom in I would like more types of roads to appear and also change the thickness of the different classes of roads.

I know that I could build a very long style that includes different rules for each scale, but I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way to set the min/max scales on groups of rules. Can max/min scales be set on groups of rules? Or, is there a better way to set up such groups? Can scale limits be set on the layer level? If that is the case I could build 5 separate layers (1 for each scale range).

Answer (score 1):

Scale denominator limits can only be set at the Rule level, sorry.
If you're looking for ways to write styles in a slightly more compact way, you can [try GeoServer own CSS variant](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/index.html) or, if you prefer YAML, [YSLD](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/ysld/index.html).
They still accept scale denominators at the rule level, but the style will be generally more compact.

Comment: In general no one should be writing SLD by hand, use udig or qgis to do it

Comment: Ah got it, yeah that's what I suspected.

@IanTurton - yes, this is how I am building the style. Does the same apply there? Or is there a way to create groups like I've described?